# Changing Chrome's settings with Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on Chrome with Selenium and I'm looking to change a few settings within Chrome using the webdriver. Using Google and this site, I was able to get most of the settings working. However, a few more seem to escape me and hopefully I can get the answers here. I'm looking to alter the settings before launching the browser, such as using `ChromeOptions`, rather than using automation to navigate the settings page.

The settings I'm looking to change are as follows:

- Disable Javascript
- Disable the microphone
- Change the home page
- Altering the default search engine in the Omnibox

These 4 are giving me the most issues. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) will help. E.g.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
caps.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--disable-javascript"));
```

And

```
Map<String, Object> preferences = Maps.newHashMap();
preferences.put( "browser.startup.homepage", "http://my.home.page" );
preferences.put( "browser.startup.page", START_WITH_HOME_PAGE );
capabilities.setCapability( ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, preferences );
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver( capabilities );
```

**Update**

My guess is that the following

```
"import_search_engine": true
```

from [Configuring other parameters](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences) will cause Chrome to ask you to select a search engine when it opens.

Turning off JavaScript makes chrome pretty much a no-op; I do not think that the option is supported. As far as microphones, that is more a system option.  A search of about:config for microphone came up empty.

Comment: I've checked that page and I only see the option for setting the homepage, which is useful, so thank you there. However, the `--disable-javascript` flag was removed on 11/14/14 as shown in an [older version of the page](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/?date=2011-06-09).  The still currently existing `--disable-javascript-harmony-shipping` flag doesn't fully disable javascript. I would still need help with the three currently unsolved issues.