# Download pdf in chrome with Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pdf, download

I'm trying to download pdf on chrome with selenium and python.
A way to do that is to turn on a setting in chrome.

[image: Setting window image]

I try to do that at the begin of my code with selenium

```
driver.get('chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('bar').click()
```

But always got an error. Same if i try to interract with everything in this window

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_selenium.py", line 37, in <module>
driver.find_element_by_id('knob').click()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"bar"}
(Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.40,platform=Linux 4.18.10-100.fc27.x86_64 x86_64)
```

Thanks for help

Comment: A possible faster alternative to changing this value with UI automation might be to use the [Print To PDF Chrome Command Line Switch](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#print-to-pdf) (or some related switch) via ChromeOptions as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36879734/2291928

Answer (score 0):

Install `chrome-printtopdf` from npm using below command.

```
pip install chrome-printtopdf
```

Use below code to download pdf file.

```
from chrome_printtopdf import get_pdf_with_chrome_sync

pdf_file = get_pdf_with_chrome_sync('http://example.org',
chrome_binary='/path/to/chrome-bin')

with open('example.org.pdf', 'wb') as f:
f.write(pdf_file.read())
```

Command line usage is mentioned below

```
python -m chrome_printtopdf /path/to/chrome-bin http://example.org/ out.pdf
```